# AUTOSAR: detect two dimensional array in model

Tags: autosar

How can I detect if an ImplementationDataTypeElement is an array that has arrays (even through typedefs) in it?

I can detect one dimensional array by detecting if category is "ARRAY" but how do I get the further "definitions"?

Comment: Out of curiosity: do you think the question was answered?

Comment: @Uwe Yes! It's working fine, thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the `ImplementationDataTypeElement` owned by an `ImplementationDataType` of `category` `ARRAY` is again of `category` `ARRAY` than you have a clear indication for a two-dimensional array.

If the `ImplementationDataTypeElement` is of `category` `TYPE_REFERENCE` then you have to look at the `ImplementationDataType` that is referenced by means of `ImplementationDataTypeElement`.`swDataDefProps`.`implementationDataType`.

If the referenced `ImplementationDataType` is of `category` `ARRAY` then this is also an indication for the definition of a two-dimensional array.